# how to convert a hash value returned from a date_select in rails to a Date object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a date_select in my view inside a form, however on submit the value returned is in a hash form like so:

```
{"(1i)"=>"2010", "(2i)"=>"8", "(3i)"=>"16"}
```

how can i convert that in to a Date format in rails so i can use it as a condition when querying the database e.g `:condition => {:dates == :some_date_from_date_select}`? i tried calling `Date.parse(:some_date_from_date_select)` but it didn't work because its expecting a string and not a hash map.

is there a rails way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know about a rails way, but this "one-liner" does the trick:

```
irb(main):036:0> d = Date.parse( {"(1i)"=>"2010", "(2i)"=>"8", "(3i)"=>"16"}.to_a.sort.collect{|c| c[1]}.join("-") )
=> #<Date: 4910849/2,0,2299161>
irb(main):037:0> d.to_s
=> "2010-08-16"
```

Or, with less magic:

```
h={"(1i)"=>"2010", "(2i)"=>"8", "(3i)"=>"16"}
d=Date.new(h['(1i)'].to_i, h['(2i)'].to_i, h['(3i)'].to_i)
d.to_s
=> "2010-08-16"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a short one line solution for this

```
params["due_date"] = {"date(3i)"=>"14", "date(2i)"=>"4", "date(1i)"=>"2014"}


params["due_date"].map{|k,v| v}.join("-").to_date
=> Mon, 14 Apr 2014
```

Comment: Is the order of the elements of a hash assured? This code seems to depend on that.

Comment: order of hash is ensured in ruby 1.9, but not in 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way to do it, which also supports partial dates/times and empty fields:

```
def date_from_date_select_fields(params, name)
  parts = (1..6).map do |e|
    params["#{name}(#{e}i)"].to_i
  end

  # remove trailing zeros
  parts = parts.slice(0, parts.rindex{|e| e != 0}.to_i + 1)
  return nil if parts[0] == 0  # empty date fields set

  Date.new(*parts)
end
```

Example usage:

```
# example input:
#
# params = {
#   "user":
#     "date_of_birth(1i)": "2010",
#     "date_of_birth(2i)": "8",
#     "date_of_birth(3i)": "16"
#   }
# }
date_of_birth = date_from_date_select_fields(params[:user], 'date_of_birth')
```

Comment: Your example didn't work for me.. but i switched:
Date.new(*parts) to Time.zone.now(parts.join("/")) then it worked  great

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.new(*params["due_date"].values.map(&:to_i))
```

Note: Works in ruby 1.9.2+ since it depends on the order of the hash elements.

Two goodies here:

- [Symbol to Proc](http://railscasts.com/episodes/6-shortcut-blocks-with-symbol-to-proc)
- [Splat operator](http://manu3569.github.io/blog/2013/10/08/what-the-splat/)

Answer (score 0):

This particular code (the one that does conversion) can be tracked from  `lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb`, line no 67 onwards, i.e. the method `type_cast`.

These two methods are used to generate a date from string:

```
def fast_string_to_date(string)
  if string =~ Format::ISO_DATE
    new_date $1.to_i, $2.to_i, $3.to_i
  end
end

# Doesn't handle time zones.
def fast_string_to_time(string)
  if string =~ Format::ISO_DATETIME
    microsec = ($7.to_f * 1_000_000).to_i
    new_time $1.to_i, $2.to_i, $3.to_i, $4.to_i, $5.to_i, $6.to_i, microsec
  end
end

# Note that ISO_DATE is:
ISO_DATE = /\A(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\z/
```