# How to parse /generate date object from rails select_date tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert a hash value returned from a date_select in rails to a Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501180/how-to-convert-a-hash-value-returned-from-a-date-select-in-rails-to-a-date-objec)

I have following date in form

```
<%= date_select(:end_date, "end",:default => Time.now , :discard_day => true)%>
```

When I submit form, it sends following request to controller

```
 "end_date"=>{"(1i)"=>"2012", "(2i)"=>"12", "(3i)"=>"1"}, ...etc
```

I want to generate Date object from above params in the controller.

My questions are;

- Am I sending params correctly ?
- How I can generate ruby Date object from above params ?

Comment: Dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501180/how-to-convert-a-hash-value-returned-from-a-date-select-in-rails-to-a-date-objec See the answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
#from your example {"end_date"=>{"(1i)"=>"2012", "(2i)"=>"12", "(3i)"=>"1"}}
Date.parse params["end_date"].values.join("-")
=> Sat, 01 Dec 2012
```